# Decomposition of $GL(n,\Bbb C)$ into positive-definite-hermitian and unitary.

Tags: linear-algebra

It is known that every matrix $A\in GL(n,\Bbb C)$ can be written uniquely as $A=PU$ for a positive-definite hermitian matrix $P$ and a unitary matrix $U\in U(n)$.

In particular if $A_1=P_1U_1$ and $A_2=P_2U_2$ are such decompositions, we should find $P$ and $U$ such that $A_1A_2=PU$.

> **Question:** Is there an expression for $P$ and $U$ in terms of $P_1,P_2,U_1,U_2$?

I tried various ways of combining the product, for example,
$$A_1A_2=(P_1U_1P_1^{-1})(P_1P_2U_2),$$
but none seems to give a decomposition into a positive-definite hermitian and a unitary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, though perhaps this is in a somewhat trivial sense.

For any invertible $A$, the $A = PU$ decomposition satisfies
$$
P = (AA^*)^{1/2}, \qquad U = (AA^*)^{-1/2}A
$$
So, we would find that if $A = A_1A_2$, then
$$
P = ((A_1A_2)(A_1A_2)^*)^{1/2} = 
(P_1U_1P_2U_1^*P_1)^{1/2}\\
U = ((A_1A_2)(A_1A_2)^*)^{-1/2}(A_1A_2) = 
(P_1U_1P_2U_1^*P_1)^{-1/2}P_1U_1P_2U_2
$$
I don't believe that we can simplify the expression further than this in general. In particular, we can't avoid computing a positive definite square root.